# Crashing while Investigating Ivy's Plant

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-knight

In Batman: Arkham Knight, after...

> the fight with the Cloudburst Tank, when you go to Ivy and open her plant,

the game crashes. It freezes for 15 seconds and then a weird error message comes up. What should I do?

[image: Crash Message]

Comment: If a question doesn't make sense without the spoiler text, it shouldn't be spoilered.

Comment: 1. Spoilers can be done by writing `>!` at the beginning of the line. 2. You can always click on `edit` to see how a user formatted a particular post to learn how it's done. 3. If you're curious, you can read this [markdown help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for reference. 4. If you can, you should give us more details about that error message. What does it say? It would be easiest to make a screenshot of it and add it to your question.

Comment: @Nolonar It says something like "bad import index". I cannot get a screenshot because I can't get Snipping Tool into the view.

Comment: Pretty much every line says "file not found" in it. Have you tried simply redownloading Batman?

Comment: @Timelord64 I have uninstalled it after it's bad launch and only reinstalled it maybe a week ago. Still waiting for that promised patch that was just "teased" to us last night.

Comment: @Nolonar I got the image up.

Comment: Most likely just a coincidence, but the same thing happened to me on PS4.  Had to restart (only once) and do that fight all over again. This happens every time for you?

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife No, I just crash every single time right outside when I look into her plant.

Comment: @Timelord64: As the author of _[Batman Tweak Tool](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=484128370)_, I can tell you those `Filename Not Found` errors are not what you are lead to believe. It is actually debug information that is missing - ordinarily there would be debug "symbols" to convert those cryptic addresses to function names, but that is missing. This actually sounds like a corrupt file.

Comment: @mugen2099: Have you tried validating your steam cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifying the cache seemed to help, at least temporarily. Still buggy. I enabled NVIDIA GameWork's settings and it looks like it helps.